# In Linux, why does an empty file have a size of 0, but a text file with any content has a size the length of the content + 1?

Tags: linux, unix, filesystems, files

This may be a *nix thing, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

An extra byte is for the line end at the end of the file, it's quite common for Linux text editors to add this line end after the last line.

Comment: The gcc compiler even complains if this blank line is not there.

Comment: @Dana the Sane, yeah and shell interpreters (at least old ones) won't interpret the last line of a shell script if it's not terminated with a line end.

Comment: Some text editors (e.g. `vim`) will also warn you if you don't have the EOL.

Answer (score 18):

Probably a trailing new-line character. For example, a file created in a text editor containing only an 'a' may actually contain 2 bytes:

```
$ cat /tmp/test_text | hexdump -C
00000000  61 0a                                             |a.|
00000002
```

However, using `echo -n` (no new line) gives us a size of 1 byte:

```
$ echo -n 'a' > /tmp/test_text 
$ ls -l /tmp/test_text 
-rw-r--r--  1 redacted  redacted  1  1 Sep 21:09 /tmp/test_text
$ cat /tmp/test_text | hexdump -C
00000000  61                                                |a|
00000001
```